# Temporary files problem

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, fsck

Recently my server started to behave weird and I have two issues which I believe to be related.

- In *Vi* :

  - When I try to save a file I get :

    ```
    E509: Cannot create backup file
    ```

    and I need to save using *:x!* - if I don't force, it does not save.
  - When I open a file I get:

    ```
    E303: Unable to open swap file for "filename", recovery impossible
    ```
  - And any time I quit, I get:

    ```
    E138: Can't write viminfo file /root/.viminfo!
    ```
- WordPress

It started to happen at the same time as the problem with Vi, all my installations of WordPress have a similar problem: every time I try to upload anything : image, theme, plugin, I get :

```
Missing a temporary folder.
```

and I cannot upload the file.

- Some element of solution:

I have tried to to fsck at reboot, it worked and the problem was fixed for a while, then it got corrupted again (a few hours later).

Any idea what's the problem? Any idea how to fix it?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on Amazon EC2

Comment: Are you out of storage space?

Comment: Please provide the output for `df -h` (storage space), `cat /etc/fstab` (to see your `/tmp` mounting), and `stat -c%a / /tmp` (permissions for `/` and `/tmp`).

Comment: `# df -h
df: cannot read table of mounted file systems`

Comment: `#cat /etc/fstab`


LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs /  ext4 defaults 0 0


/dev/xvdf swap swap defaults 0   0

Comment: `# stat -c%a / /tmp`


755
1777

Comment: ok I just clean the postfix queue, freed like 4Gig - now df -h return 

`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  4.7G  2.8G  63% /
udev            288M   12K  288M   1% /dev
tmpfs           119M  172K  118M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            296M     0  296M   0% /run/shm`

Comment: @Johann Savalle, edit these into your question for readability.

Comment: This question should be referenced next time someone asks why you'd want separate partitions for /var and others instead of a single partition.

Comment: @casey protip: if you put [square brackets] around the word edit, it will turn into a link, like this: [edit]

Comment: @strugee thanks.  It seems I'm learning something about the markdown on SE everyday.

Comment: @casey -- I need to improve my markdown skills indeed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When ever you run into an issue where you think you're out of diskspace or you're running out of diskspace there are 2 commands you can run to confirm this.

**NOTE:** Be aware that in addition to running out of diskspace, you might also be running out of inodes.

#### df

The command `df` is the venerable tool for reporting on filesystem usage.

#### Example

It has 2 switches that you'll likely use most of the time. Either `-h` or `-k`. I always opt for `-h` since this shows the disk space in human readable units.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root   50G   11G   36G  23% /
devtmpfs                           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              3.9G  2.3M  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              3.9G 1016K  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                              3.9G  1.1G  2.8G  27% /tmp
/dev/sda1                          477M  101M  348M  23% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home  402G  146G  236G  39% /home
```

Notice that my `/tmp` is configured with 3.9GB or which 1.1GB is used.

#### tune2fs

This command is a bit more obscure but is useful when you want to confirm if your system if running out of inodes. Believe it or not, but inodes is a limited resource that you allocate during the creation phase of your filesystem. Once allocated it cannot be changed.

I'd check to see if your system has run out of inodes.

#### Example

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root | grep -i "inode"
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Inode count:              3276800
Free inodes:              3060507
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       1321314
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

So with the above you'll notice that we have 3276800 inode of which 3060507 are available.

#### Alternative inode method

There are several other ways you can do this. Certain versions of the `df` command can also report inodes.

```
$ df -i
Filesystem                          Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root  3276800 226065  3050735    7% /
devtmpfs                            994457    480   993977    1% /dev
tmpfs                               996186     19   996167    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                               996186    623   995563    1% /run
tmpfs                               996186     12   996174    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                               996186    230   995956    1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                           128016    320   127696    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-home 26722304 908502 25813802    4% /home
```

Comment: `tune2fs` will only work if OP is running a ext* filesystem. I believe some distros are starting to experimentally ship with btrfs roots by default nowadays.

Comment: @strugee -  thanks for clarifying that. I hadn't heard of this. Know which distros this might be? BTW, he's on a VPS on Amazon so I highly doubt this will be an issue there.

Comment: true. I thought it was Red Hat, but that didn't seem right so I Googled. looks like I was remembering wrong; I must have been thinking of the _option_ for btrfs being included, not being set as the default.

Comment: @strugee - that makes more sense, I could see it being offered as an option, but making it a default, seems like a few years off, until btrfs has aged a bit more.

Comment: yeah, I was a bit skeptical writing that comment...

Comment: thanks for this extensive answer. It was actually a lack of free space (postfix mail queue blotted with spam... an other issue to fix). Once I cleaned the mail queue and halted postfix, everything went back to normal

Comment: @JohannSavalle - glad you system is back to normal. I've run out of diskspace & inodes so it's something to always keep in the back of your mind when dealing with Unix systems.